# Menu bar flashes for a moment when Emacs starts

Tags: emacs, elisp

With `(menu-bar-mode 0)` in my `.emacs`-file, Emacs (in a terminal) seems to be starting with the menu bar visible, and then within a fraction of a second, the bar disappears.

Is there a way to make Emacs not show the menu bar at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: Emacs first starts by setting up its "frame" (which includes some initial display), then reads the .emacs file.  That's why you see this flashing of the menu-bar.  Emacs could read the .emacs first, but if the .emacs outputs any message or signals an error, there'd only be stderr to display it, whereas with the current setup, those messages are displayed in the minibuffer and the error can be caught in the "normal" way.

Comment: It would be nice if the menu bar was inhibited when the initial frame is drawn, though (who uses the menu anyway? :-)

Comment: Please see my answer for a solution using Xresources.

Comment: @tripleee: What you're asking is to disable the menu by default on tty frames.  Feel free to request this via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  I wouldn't be opposed to such a change, but I don't feel it's very important either.

Answer (score 2):

If you're runinng Linux (and I guess any system where Emacs runs in an X server), you can use X resources to tell Emacs you don't want the menu bar. Just put this in your `~/.Xresources` file:

```
emacs.menuBar: off
```

These resources are used to customize frames appearance and are therefore read by Emacs at the very beginning.

See also:

- [Emacs manual: Menu Bars](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Menu-Bars.html#Menu-Bars)
- [Emacs manual: Table of Resources](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Table-of-Resources.html#Table-of-Resources)
- [man xrdb(1)](http://man.cx/xrdb)

Comment: Thanks! Those who use X must be lucky!